# How to fix the width of textarea in number of characters? (cols attribute does NOT work)

Tags: html, css

I want to specify the width of textareas in terms of the maximum numbers of *monospace* characters they should be able to hold in each line *with neither excess leftover space nor overflow*.

There are a few SO similar questions, but the consensus answer, namely to use the `cols` attribute, decidedly does not work, as shown in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kynn/198fo39c/).  The HTML for it is this:

```
<textarea cols="1"  rows="2">1</textarea><br/>
<textarea cols="10" rows="2">1234567890</textarea><br/>
<textarea cols="20" rows="2">12345678901234567890</textarea><br/>
<textarea cols="40" rows="2">1234567890123456789012345678901234567890</textarea><br/>
<textarea cols="80" rows="2">12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</textarea><br/>
```

The actual width is always substantially greater than the necessary width.  (In Safari at least the excess seems to remain constant, irrespective of the specified value of `cols`; with Chrome, however, the excess grows as the value of `cols` grows.)

I also tried using the CSS `width` property with [`em`](http://jsfiddle.net/kynn/uj21Lqv4/) and [`ex`](http://jsfiddle.net/kynn/ke41u0vp/) units.  The latter results in fields that are several characters narrower than needed, while the former results in even greater widths than those resulting from the `cols` attribute.

Finally, I investigated setting the width, in ex units, as the number obtained by multiplying the number of characters by some fudge factor.  This is not only disgusting (we shouldn't be doing the browser's work), but also is not cross-browser: the fudge factors I found for Chrome and Safari (for example) are substantially different (1.333 vs 1.415).

Is there a professional<sup>1</sup> way to do this?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>i.e. cross-browser, guesswork-free, hack-free, documented, well-thought-out, etc.</sup>

Comment: Though it's not really much of a stand-alone answer, I wanted to point out the `contenteditable` attribute. Perhaps someone could think of a solution using it.. http://jsfiddle.net/c230v4kx/

Comment: override the font for `<textarea>` elements to be fixed width and then set the element width in `em` or `ex` units

Comment: @StephenThomas: I already did what you propose, as described in considerable detail in my original post; I also explained in detail why this solution fails.

Comment: You have to use a fixed width font

Comment: @StephenThomas: the jsFiddle I posted uses a fixed width font.

Comment: But (a) you didn't set the width of the textarea, and (b) you're using the generic monospace font, which isn't the same on all systems. See codepen in my answer below if you want a working solution.

Comment: @StephenThomas: I *did* set the textarea width in the relevant jsFiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/kynn/uj21Lqv4/ and http://jsfiddle.net/kynn/ke41u0vp/, which were included in my original post.  Look at the HTML.  And the problem I mentioned (significant cross-browser variance) is exactly the same with courier or monospace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `col` attribute gives accurate results, but the width is somewhat larger than needed for the characters, since there is room for vertical scroll bar on the right (or left, depending on directionality). You can see this by entering a few more lines in the area.

You can remove the room for scroll bar by removing scrollability, using `overflow: hidden`.

An alternative to set the width in [`ch` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Font-relative_lengths), but browser support is more limited.

```css
textarea {
    resize:none;
    background-color:lightgray;
    padding:0;
    font-family: monospace;
}
.fix {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.w18 {
    width: 18ch;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="18" rows="2">123456789012345678</textarea>
<p>See what happens when vertical scrolling is needed:<br>
<textarea cols="18" rows="2">123456789012345678
123
123</textarea>
<p>Fixed by removing space for scroll bar:<br>
<textarea cols="18" rows="2" class="fix">123456789012345678</textarea>
<p>Fixed by setting width in `ch` units:<br>
<textarea cols="18" rows="2" class="w18">123456789012345678</textarea>
```

As the demo shows, `overflow: hidden` also removes the space for a horizontal scroll bar. Browsers generally leave such a space, so that the area seems to have one row more than the value of `rows`, even though browsers normally do not show a horizontal scroll bar as they used to (they visually break lines instead). Using `overflow-y: hidden` instead keeps that space

You need to consider what the removal of scroll bars implies in terms of usability. If the intent is to show the user the maximum allowed line length, maybe you can do that by *forcing* a scroll bar instead of removing it.

```html
<textarea cols="18" rows="2" style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; resize: none">123456789012345678</textarea>
```

Comment: For the `.w18` one, I had to increase the width to accomodate for the borders, which take up a tiny space. Otherwise only 17 characters fit in a row. (Strangely, in the snippet this works fine.)

Answer (score 0):

It's debatable whether this qualifies as professional, but you can style the `textarea` to use a fixed width font

```
textarea {
    font-family: Courier;
}
```

and then set its width in either `em` or `ex` units. The exact width to use, however, will depend on the specific font and it may be subject to slight differences in browser font rendering. Here's an example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/sathomas/pen/rawKLw).

With this approach the "fudge factor" won't have as wide as a variance (it's pretty much the same on all browsers), but you're limited to fonts that you're confident will be available on the client. Courier is probably the closest you can get to being safe in most cases.

Here's the result in Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

and Safari:

[image]

As you can see, there are definite differences in how the browsers compute a default font size, but in all cases they correctly set the width of the text area to the specified number of characters.

Comment: actually, you didn't, but feel free to be a jerk about it anyway

Comment: This solution is described in excruciating detail in my post, down to specific multipliers for a couple of browsers.  The only difference is that you used "Courier" while I used "monospace".  The upshot is exactly the same.  And so are my objections to it.

Comment: Yes, but if you use Courier instead of the generic monospace, you won't have the wide variance in multipliers, which is the stated objection to the approach. If you check out the referenced codepen, you'll see that it works cross-browser. I did note right at the start, that the solution may not be "professional," but it was offered as a possible approach.

Comment: This is *NOT* true: (a) I get ***exactly*** the same multipliers with Courier as I get with monospace. (b) on Safari, the text in your codepen spills over to the second line; it does not fit in one line with the specified width, which is consistent with the fact that I get greater multipliers for Safari than for, say, Chrome.

Comment: The answer omits essential details of the proposed approach, and specific values are given only on the linked page. Moreover, the results are not correct: the width seems to be too wide or too narrow, depending on browser.